# Sum of partial factorials: number of digits for $\sum_{n=1}^{256}\frac{256!}{(256 - n)!}$

Tags: summation, factorial

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=256!), $256! \approx 8.5 \times 10^{506}$, i.e. it has $507$ digits. My question is how can one evaluate such approximations for this sum below?:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{256}\frac{256!}{(256 - n)!} = 256 + 256 \times 255 + 256 \times 255 \times 254 + \dots + 256! $

Comment: Not a step to answer the question, but I find simpler this way to write it: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{256}\frac{256!}{n!}$

Comment: Note that the largest i.e. "leading" term is sufficiently large that the number of digits will almost certainly be the number of digits in that term. So there are two things to check - first the number of digits in the leading term, and second whether the leading term is such that a relatively small addition will change the number of digits. For both you simply need a good enough approximation of the leading term.

Comment: Since $e\cdot8.5>10$, the number of digits of the result is $$\color{red}{\bf 508}$$

Comment: @ajotatxe This sum you wrote is not the same, unless you change the bounds of the summation to 0 and 255. And while I agree that \sum_{n=0}^{255}\frac{256!}{n!} looks simpler, I chose that form in my question because the ordered expansion seemed simpler to me: $256 + 256 \times 255 + 256 \times 255 \times 254 + \dots + 256!$. Reversing the bounds or writing the expansion in a reverse ordered didn't look good. Anyway, I believe they are all the same way of writing the same thing, and I think what I wrote above is still simple enough.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{256}\frac{256!}{n!}\approx256!\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}=(e-1)\cdot256!$$

Comment: The relevant sum is actually $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{255}$ and the factor is $e$, not $e-1$.

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{256}\frac{256!}{(256 - n)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{255}\frac{256!}{n!} \neq \sum_{n=1}^{256}\frac{256!}{n!}$. Actually, I believe that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{256}\frac{256!}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{256}\frac{256!}{(256 - n)!} - 256! + 1$